# JavaScript critical error at line 135, column 158 in http://localhost:31424/Default.aspx SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'

Tags: c#, javascript, scriptmanager

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "jscript", "alert('This browser is currently not supported on the website. Please use either latest version of Chrome or Mozilla Firefox. Click here to download<a href='~/CheckBrowser.aspx'>Download</a>');", true);


alert('This browser is currently not supported on the website. Please use either latest version of Chrome or Mozilla Firefox. Click here to download<a href='~/CheckBrowser.aspx'>Download</a>');(function() {var fn = function() {$get("ctl08_HiddenField").value = '';Sys.Application.remove_init(fn);};Sys.Application.add_init(fn);})();//]]>


**JavaScript critical error at line 135, column 158 in http://localhost:31424/Default.aspx  SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'**
```

I am getting this error can't figure out what the error is

Comment: perhaps quotationmarks set wrong? The Interpreter is complaining about a missing bracked ')'. But perhaps if you set the wrong number of quotationmarks it would misinterpret the number of closing brackets

Comment: You're using the same single quotation marks for to encapsulate the `<a href` value. I guess that breaks the content of your `alert`. Because it now gets this: `alert('blabla...<a href='` and then you close the content of the `alert`. So you need to escape the quotes there with `\`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape quote like this :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "jscript", "alert('This browser is currently not supported on the website. Please use either latest version of Chrome or Mozilla Firefox. Click here to download<a href=\'~/CheckBrowser.aspx\'>Download</a>');", true);


alert('This browser is currently not supported on the website. Please use either latest version of Chrome or Mozilla Firefox. Click here to download<a href=\'~/CheckBrowser.aspx\'>Download</a>');(function() {var fn = function() {$get("ctl08_HiddenField").value = '';Sys.Application.remove_init(fn);};Sys.Application.add_init(fn);})();//]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "jscript", "alert('This browser is currently not supported on the website. Please use either latest version of Chrome or Mozilla Firefox. Click here to download<a href=\'~/CheckBrowser.aspx\'>Download</a>');", true);
```

Comment: JavaScript critical error at line 135, column 158 in http://localhost:31424/Default.aspx

SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'

Comment: @vini try again to copy the first snippet and try it

Comment: the popup doesn't open now

Comment: then you should try without \' only with '